# How to figure out my Kerberos principal on Windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, active-directory, kerberos

On a Unix system with Kerberos configured, I'd use `klist`...

How does one query his Kerberos principal(s) on Windows?

(Using the Active Directory, not MIT implementation.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One would use also `klist`. Your principal name is in the "Client:" field of every ticket.

```
H:\> klist

Current LogonId is 0:0x494539

Cached Tickets: (2)

#0>     Client: fred @ AD.EXAMPLE.COM
        Server: krbtgt/AD.EXAMPLE.COM @ AD.EXAMPLE.COM
        KerbTicket Encryption Type: AES-256-CTS-HMAC-SHA1-96
        Ticket Flags 0x40e00000 -> forwardable renewable initial pre_authent
        Start Time: 11/11/2020 17:49:42 (local)
        End Time:   11/12/2020 3:49:42 (local)
        Renew Time: 11/18/2020 17:49:42 (local)
        Session Key Type: AES-256-CTS-HMAC-SHA1-96
        Cache Flags: 0x1 -> PRIMARY
        Kdc Called: dc1.ad.example.com

#1>     Client: fred @ AD.EXAMPLE.COM
        Server: ldap/dc1.ad.example.com @ AD.EXAMPLE.COM
        ...
```

Note that the Kerberos principal name is not the same as the Active Directory UPN (which you can see using `whoami /upn`). One AD domain always has exactly one Kerberos realm, while its users can have several UPN suffixes.

This command is available in all recent Windows versions – built-in since Windows Vista or Win7 (approximately), but it was also downloadable for XP and Server 2003 as part of the "Server 2003 Resource Kit". Older versions require a subcommand, such as `klist tickets` or `klist tgt`.

Having Java installed might override the command, as Java has its own Kerberos implementation (separate from MIT Krb5). The correct one is found in `\Windows\System32`.

```
C:\Users> where klist

C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jre-14.0.2.12-hotspot\bin\klist.exe
C:\Windows\System32\klist.exe
```